# Skip iterating on itself (List)

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to find similar emails in a list. For this,

`database.head()`

```
    TID PID Names
0   22330   134575  tim
1   22333   134578  tim.rand
2   22328   134571  rand.001
3   22340   134568  pankit090
4   22325   134569  timrook
```

`emailsdb = database['Names'].values.tolist()`
Now the iteration part

```
list = []
for email in emailsdb :
    result = process.extractBests(email, emailsdb, score_cutoff=85, limit=100)
    list.append(result)
```

The list output is

```
[[('tim', 100), ('tim.rand', 90), ('timrook', 90)],
 [('tim.rand', 100), ('tim', 90)],
 [('rand.001', 100)],
 [('pankit090', 100),
  ('pankit001', 89),
  ('pankit002', 89),
  ('pankit003', 89),
  ('pankit004', 89),
  ('pankit005', 89)],
 [('timrook', 100), ('tim', 90)],
 [('pankit001', 100),
  ('pankit090', 89),
  ('pankit002', 89),
  ('pankit003', 89),
  ('pankit004', 89),
  ('pankit005', 89)],
 [('pankit002', 100),
  ('pankit090', 89),
  ('pankit001', 89),
  ('pankit003', 89),
  ('pankit004', 89),
  ('pankit005', 89)],
```

but I want to avoid ('tim', 100), ('tim.rand', 100), ('rand.001', 100), ('pankit090', 100), ('timrook', 100), ('pankit001', 100),('pankit002', 100) because these are obviously perfect match

Comment: Based on the wuzzy docs, I don't see a way to skip the 100 matches. You will probably just need to remove them from the list after the extract call.

Comment: What if we remove copy of list with email removed in for loop

Comment: Yes - That should work also

Comment: list = []
for email in emailsdb :
    newlookup = emailsdb.copy()
    newlookup.remove(email)
    result = process.extractBests(email, newlookup, score_cutoff=85, limit=50)
    list.append(email)
    list.append(result)

Comment: here the result is of the format - [email, [match1,score],[match2,score], email, [match3,score],[match4,score]]. How can I extract match1, match2, match3, match4 and remove them emailsdb from further lookup

Comment: check my answer with a potential solution.

Comment: Check my new answer with the solution of what we talked about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as another answer since this solves it in a completely different way, in light of the discussion we had on chat.

Approach -

1. If you use a commutative function to get string matches, then you can actually compute only the lower triangular matrix of the distance matrix since f(x,y) will be the same as f(y,x).
2. Fuzzy ratio is NOT commutative while Levenshtein distance (aka edit distance, which is the foundation of fuzzy matching) is commutative. Here instead getting maximum score, you are finding strings with the minimum lev distance between them
3. So first you take the indexes for lower triangular matrix and iterate over them to calculate the lev distance of the emails with those indexes. You DONT iterate on the diagonal of the distance matrix f(x,x) because its trivial, and later you set it as a high value like 999 so that you can find the min score values in each row.
4. This gives you the distance matrix (see output). Next for each row (email) you find the nearest string (minimum distance) and create it as a tuple of Best Matches (see output)
5. Now, the issue here is that even if NONE of the string match that well, it will still greedily get the nearest one.
6. So finally you can take the fuzz.ratio between these strings and get fuzzy scores, which you can filter on. So now, you can avoid garbage matches and only get the ones which truely match above a certain threshold. This gives Final Matching strings (see output)

This should be probably the best you can do with optimizing the code from an algorithmic perspective.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#!pip install python-Levenshtein
from Levenshtein import distance
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

#CHECKING COMMUTATIVE PROPERTY
distance('abcd','bdca') == distance('bdca', 'abcd')
###OUTPUT - TRUE

fuzz.ratio('abcd','bdca') == fuzz.ratio('bdca', 'abcd')
###OUTPUT - FALSE


#Create dummy matrix
m = np.zeros((len(emailsdb),len(emailsdb)))

#Get lower triangular matrix indices
i,j = np.tril_indices(len(emailsdb))

#iterate over lower triangular and get Levenshtein distance for lower triangular
for k in zip(i,j):
    if k[0]!=k[1]:
        m[k] = distance(emailsdb[k[0]], emailsdb[k[1]])
    else:
        m[k] = 0

#Copy lower triangular to upper traingular thanks to COMMUTATIVE PROPERTY
m = m + m.T

#Filling diagonal with 999 so that same string doesnt show up with minimum distance
np.fill_diagonal(m, 999)
print("distance matrix = ")
print(m)

#Get best matches with minimum distance
matches = list(zip([i for i in emailsdb], [emailsdb[i] for i in np.argmin(m, axis=0)]))

print("Best matches = ")
print(matches)


#OPTIONAL -> Filtering out irrelavant matches based on fuzzy match
f = [(*i,fuzz.ratio(*i)) for i in matches if fuzz.ratio(*i)>50]

print("final matching strings - ")
print(f)
```

```
distance matrix = 
[[999.   5.   8.   8.   4.]
 [  5. 999.   8.   9.   4.]
 [  8.   8. 999.   6.   8.]
 [  8.   9.   6. 999.   9.]
 [  4.   4.   8.   9. 999.]]


Best matches = 
[('tim', 'timrook'), ('tim.rand', 'timrook'), ('rand.001', 'pankit090'), ('pankit090', 'rand.001'), ('timrook', 'tim')]


final matching strings - 
[('tim', 'timrook', 60), ('tim.rand', 'timrook', 53), ('timrook', 'tim', 60)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to process the fuzzy lookup then remove the results for the original email list. Since this is a short list, removing the match list has the same effect as just clearing the original list. Note that the remove process could be included in the first email loop, but I left them separate for clarity. I added the zzzz entry to check scoring.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

# original email list
emailsdb = [
'tim',
'tim.rand',
'rand.001',
'pankit090',
'timrook',
'pankit001',
'pankit002',
'pankit003',
'pankit004',
'pankit005',
'zzzz'
]

print('emailsdb:', emailsdb)

# do fuzzy search and score other emails (including self)
lstres = []
for email in emailsdb :
    result = process.extractBests(email, emailsdb, score_cutoff=85, limit=50)
    lstres.append(result)
    
print('WuzzyResult:', lstres)

# scan match list and create set 
setremove = set()  # no duplicates
for r in lstres:
   setremove |= ({t[0] for t in r})
   
print('setremove:', setremove)

# remove matches from original set
for e in setremove:
   emailsdb.remove(e)
   
print('emailsdb:', emailsdb)
```

Output:

```
emailsdb: ['tim', 'tim.rand', 'rand.001', 'pankit090', 'timrook', 'pankit001', 'pankit002', 'pankit003', 'pankit004', 'pankit005', 'zzzz']

WuzzyResult: [
[('tim', 100), ('tim.rand', 90), ('timrook', 90)], 
[('tim.rand', 100), ('tim', 90)], [('rand.001', 100)], 
[('pankit090', 100), ('pankit001', 89), ('pankit002', 89), ('pankit003', 89), ('pankit004', 89), ('pankit005', 89)], 
[('timrook', 100), ('tim', 90)], 
[('pankit001', 100), ('pankit090', 89), ('pankit002', 89), ('pankit003', 89), ('pankit004', 89), ('pankit005', 89)], 
[('pankit002', 100), ('pankit090', 89), ('pankit001', 89), ('pankit003', 89), ('pankit004', 89), ('pankit005', 89)], 
[('pankit003', 100), ('pankit090', 89), ('pankit001', 89), ('pankit002', 89), ('pankit004', 89), ('pankit005', 89)], 
[('pankit004', 100), ('pankit090', 89), ('pankit001', 89), ('pankit002', 89), ('pankit003', 89), ('pankit005', 89)], 
[('pankit005', 100), ('pankit090', 89), ('pankit001', 89), ('pankit002', 89), ('pankit003', 89), ('pankit004', 89)], 
[('zzzz', 100)]
]

setremove: {'pankit002', 'pankit005', 'tim', 'rand.001', 'pankit003', 'zzzz', 'pankit090', 'pankit001', 'timrook', 'pankit004', 'tim.rand'}

emailsdb: []
```

Comment: Hi Mike, the output shows ('tim', 100), ('tim.rand', 100), ('pankit090', 100) etc...This was not intended.

Comment: So you want to remove the '100' entries from the WuzzyResult ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the items that you know (maybe by pre-defined knowledge) that you don't want to compare. This can be done by poping these items out and then comparing them, then inserting them back.

This should solve a part of your problem. I simply `pop` the same element from the list before comparison, and then `insert` it back before the next loop. Check the printed output for more details -

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

emailsdb = list(df['Names'])

l = []
for i in range(len(emailsdb)) : 
    email = emailsdb[i] #Popping based on index, rather than comparing email in emailsdb
    emailsdb.pop(i) #Pop the same email string in the list of emails
    print("comparing:",[email],'->',emailsdb)
    result = process.extractBests(email, emailsdb, score_cutoff=85, limit=100)
    l.append(result)
    emailsdb.insert(i, email) #Insert it back

print(l)
```

```
comparing: ['tim'] -> ['tim.rand', 'rand.001', 'pankit090', 'timrook']
comparing: ['tim.rand'] -> ['tim', 'rand.001', 'pankit090', 'timrook']
comparing: ['rand.001'] -> ['tim', 'tim.rand', 'pankit090', 'timrook']
comparing: ['pankit090'] -> ['tim', 'tim.rand', 'rand.001', 'timrook']
comparing: ['timrook'] -> ['tim', 'tim.rand', 'rand.001', 'pankit090']

[[('tim.rand', 90), ('timrook', 90)], [('tim', 90)], [], [], [('tim', 90)]]
```

As you can see, the redundant comparisons are not part of the output.

> Notice, I am NOT COMPARING the email that is there in the email list to the whole email list for removing it. I am simply removing the 0th, 1st, 2nd ... index email from the email list, utilizing the sequential nature of the iteration to remove the email. This is a significant speedup.

You can modify this approach to work with sets of items that you already know are similar and don't need to be compared.

P.S: Please please please please, don't use `list` as a variable name :)

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned poping out the element to be compared with itself is a significant speed up. You think so ? Can we instead remove the emails which came in similar list already e.g. in 1st run, we got ('tim.rand', 'timrook'). Can we remove ('tim.rand', 'timrook') to be iterated on.

Comment: You could, but then it's extremely dependent on how many 'similar' emails are there on average for each string. Plus the 1st run is going to make a bomb of time for larger datasets. Plus, if you have already computed similarities for all of the strings, why do a second run, just filter out the ==100 scores. This means 2 iterations of n^2 complexity.

Comment: Here, even though you have a compare more stuff on average, there is only a single iteration with n^2-1 complexity.

Comment: Note, Fuzzy matching is extremely heavy (Levenstein distance is quite a heavy algorithm) and you would prefer having a minimum number of calls to it as possible because THAT is the slowest cog in the machinery.

Comment: The ones with == 100 score are now not there because they are already removed. I want to remove ('tim.rand', 'timrook') so that they don't have to be compared with everything again. It will result in speed up.

Comment: But the first run is already comparing all of them right? So why do you want to do a second run after removing ('tim.rand', 'timrook') which would result in the same scores (just without 2 comparisons)

Comment: Suggestion to speed up? I have 50 K usernames in actual data. I want to create groups of very similar ones.

Comment: You could try using multi-processing to map the match onto n cores, asynchronously. If you have 50K usernames, you are going to do 50k*50k comparisons in first run and then after removing some scores, do another n^2 order comparisons where n is a bit lesser than 50k. Why do it 2 times?

Comment: What you can do, is this -  Imagine a matrix with indexes and columns as your strings. and the values of the matrix as the scores. You can reduce your computation time by half if you just compute score of the lower half of the matrix, because they will be identical to the upper half.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220385/discussion-between-rkapoor-and-akshay-sehgal).